# How do I enable WebGL in Xamarin.Forms WebView on UWP?

Tags: windows, webview, xamarin.forms, uwp, webgl

I’m new to Xamarin.Forms and tried using WebView on my Windows 10 x64 v1803 machine with UWP but I can’t see how to get it to work with WebGL.

Sites which use WebGL either display a message that “Your video card does not support WebGL or just don’t display and graphical content at all.

Is this a limitation of UWP or WebView itself?

Is it a WebView configuration issue?

WebGL works in all other browsers on this machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP `WebView` control is support WebGL. There is similar [issue case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9d7e063b-e281-4234-bfed-30e6626f26b2/rs41803webview-canamp39t-run-webgl-under-windows-1803?forum=wpdevelop) in msdn you could refer. Please try to use `SeparateProcess` mode WebView to replace the default one.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var MyWebView = new WebView(WebViewExecutionMode.SeparateProcess);
    MyWebView.Source = new Uri("http://cycleblob.com/");
    this.RootGrid.Children.Add(MyWebView);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to specify SeparateProcess mode in XAML?

Comment: This is can't specify in xaml, I think you could custom `WebViewRenderer` and initialize it with `SeparateProcess`.

Comment: Thanks Nico - the question has been answered and will be a great help :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but with the newer Xamarin Forms it took a little more poking around to get this took work right. However, I do like that they moved the native WebView resolver back to the responsibility of the UWP/iOS/Android project (as a native XAML object) instead of using code branching with compiler directives in the Shared project.

Start by creating a HybridWebView class in the shared project to use as your WebForm view object:

```
public class HybridWebView : Xamarin.Forms.WebView
{
    Action<string> action;

    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Uri",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(HybridWebView),
        defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }

    public void RegisterAction(Action<string> callback)
    {
        action = callback;
    }

    public void Cleanup()
    {
        action = null;
    }

    public void InvokeAction(string data)
    {
        if (action == null || data == null)        
        {
            return;
        }
        action.Invoke(data);
    }
}
```

Then in the UWP project, create a custom renderer, which will construct the native WebView and relay the events back to the WebForms object in the Shared project:

Put this at the top of the namespace, to link the HybridWebView with the Custom Renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(WebViewRenderer2))]
```

Then create the renderer class (for the IOS and android projects, if you leave this class out, it defaults to the standard native controls which seem to work fine for me):

```
public class WebViewRenderer2 : ViewRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.WebView, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView>, IWebViewDelegate
    {
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView _control;

        public void LoadHtml(string html, string baseUrl)
        {

        }

        public void LoadUrl(string url)
        {

        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            if (_control == null) {
                _control = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView(WebViewExecutionMode.SeparateProcess);
                SetNativeControl(_control);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var xamWebView = sender as HybridWebView;
            switch(e.PropertyName.ToLower())
            {
                case "source":
                    var urlSource = xamWebView.Source as Xamarin.Forms.UrlWebViewSource;
                    _control.Source = new Uri(urlSource.Url);
                    break;
                case "width":
                    _control.Width = xamWebView.Width;
                    break;
                case "height":
                    _control.Height = xamWebView.Height;
                    break;
                case "isfocused":
                    var focused = xamWebView.IsFocused;
                    if (focused)
                        _control.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
                    else
                        _control.Focus(FocusState.Unfocused);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

You can also use the Custom Renderer to inject scripts, and you can use it to communicate from the native webview back to the Xamarin App, as seen here: [HybridWebView Communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-hybridwebview/)