# How to fix crash problem when using WebView in SeparateProcess execution mode?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, xaml, uwp

In order to use WebGL in UWP `WebView` , I looked for this.

[How do I enable WebGL in Xamarin.Forms WebView on UWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598522/how-do-i-enable-webgl-in-xamarin-forms-webview-on-uwp)

But a new problem comes. When navigating to another page and go back for a few times, the application crashed and gives you no explain. It seems like too many `webview` instance was created then I tried to use Singleton pattern to solve it.

```cs
    public static class WebViewSingleton
    {
        private static WebView instance;

        public static WebView GetInstance()
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new WebView(WebViewExecutionMode.SeparateProcess)
                {
                    Source = new Uri("https://www.google.com/")
                };
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

```cs
public HomePage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MyWebView = WebViewSingleton.GetInstance();
    MyWebView.Navigate(new Uri("https://sketchfab.com/models/a6af6d1ae2744a55820d00599aca71f2/embed? 
    autostart=1&internal=1&ui_infos=0&ui_snapshots=1&ui_stop=0&ui_watermark=0"));
    this.RootGrid.Children.Add(MyWebView);
}
```

In this way, debugger tells me `MyWebView` is already a children for another element. I tried every way to disconnect `MyWebView` with it's parent but failed.

I find it works when adding `NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"` to my page, but that is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to page.xmal

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.RootGrid.Children.Contains(MyWebView))
    {
         this.RootGrid.Children.Remove(MyWebView);
    }
}
```